# Pass input value from one component to another in Angular

Tags: angular, web, angular-material

I have two components, payment-info and confirmation.
I'm trying to pass the input from payment-info into confirmation using a service (not parent/child relation). Right now the confirmation.component.html page will display the 'NA' text from the service model, but that value isn't being updated for some reason. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my payment-info.component.ts file code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { PaymentInfoService } from '../services/payment-info.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment-info',
  templateUrl: './payment-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment-info.component.css']
})
export class PaymentInfoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private paymentInfoService: PaymentInfoService
  ) { }

  paymentInfo = this.paymentInfoService.getPaymentInfo();

  checkoutForm = this.formBuilder.nonNullable.group({
    cardNumber: ''
  })

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    this.setData(this.checkoutForm.value.cardNumber!);
  }

  setData(cardNumber: string) {
    this.paymentInfoService.setPaymentInfo(cardNumber);
  }

}
```

Here is my payment-info.component.html code:

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-title>Payment Details</mat-card-title>
  <mat-card-content>
    <form [formGroup]="checkoutForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

      <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
              <mat-form-field class="inputs">
                <input matInput id="cardNumber" formControlName="cardNumber" placeholder="Card Number">
              </mat-form-field>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </table>

        <button mat-raised-button color="accent" routerLink="/confirmation" type="submit" class="confirm-button">Confirm Purchase</button>
    </form>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Here is the code for confirmation.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PaymentInfoService } from '../services/payment-info.service';
import { Payment } from '../shared/models/Payment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-confirmation',
  templateUrl: './confirmation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confirmation.component.css']
})
export class ConfirmationComponent {
  payment! : Payment;
  constructor(private paymentInfoService: PaymentInfoService) {
    this.updatePaymentInfo();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  updatePaymentInfo(){
    this.payment = this.paymentInfoService.getPaymentInfo();
  }
}
```

Here is my code for confirmation.component.html:

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-title>CONFIRMATION</mat-card-title>
<mat-card-content>
  <form>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <mat-form-field class="inputs">
            <p>{{payment.cardNumber}}</p>
        </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" routerLink="/" type="submit" class="confirm-button">Return to catalog</button>
  </form>
</mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Here is my payment-info.service.ts code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Payment } from '../shared/models/Payment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PaymentInfoService {

  paymentInfo: Payment = new Payment();

  setPaymentInfo(cardHolder:String, cardNumber: String, cvv: String, expirationDate: String){
    this.paymentInfo.cardNumber = cardNumber;
  }
  getPaymentInfo() {
    return this.paymentInfo;
  }
}
```

Lastly, here is the model I'm using for storing the input (Payment.ts):

```
export class Payment{
    cardNumber?: String = 'NA';
}
```

Comment: Try to create a https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular solution and share the link, that will be helpful to answer.

Comment: You can use Subject/BehaviorSubject in such scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem(s) & Concern(s)

**Problem: The button didn't trigger the `onSubmit` function.**

```
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" routerLink="/confirmation" type="submit" class="confirm-button">Confirm Purchase</button>
```

You may place a debugger that the `onSubmit` function is not triggered and instead, it redirects to the confirmation page.

**Concern 1: Incorrect calling `setPaymentInfo` method**

From the `PaymentService`'s `setPaymentInfo` method:

```js
setPaymentInfo(
  cardHolder: String,
  cardNumber: String,
  cvv: String,
  expirationDate: String
) {
  this.paymentInfo.cardNumber = cardNumber;
}
```

While in `PaymentInfoComponent`:

```js
setData(cardNumber: string) {
  this.paymentInfoService.setPaymentInfo(cardNumber);
}
```

You are incorrectly calling the method by providing parameters' values that do not match the method definition. You will get the compilation error.

You have to call the `setPaymentInfo` method by matching the method definition correctly as below:

```js
setData(cardNumber: string) {
  this.paymentInfoService.setPaymentInfo('', cardNumber, '', '');
}
```

**Concern 2: `MatFormField` error**

In the confirmation page, the below HTML will get an error as **`MatFormField` requires containing the `MatFormFieldControl`**

```
<mat-form-field class="inputs">
   <p>{{payment.cardNumber}}</p>
</mat-form-field>
```

Hence, you need to perform either of these actions:

1. Remove the `<mat-form-field>` element as not required.
2. Provide `MatFormFieldControl` to `<mat-form-field>` element.

```
<mat-form-field class="inputs">
   <input matInput [value]="payment.cardNumber" readonly />
</mat-form-field>
```

---

### Solution

1. Modify the Payment Info page's submit button to remove the `routerLink` attribute.

```
<button
  mat-raised-button
  color="accent"
  type="submit"
  class="confirm-button"
>
  Confirm Purchase
</button>
```

2. Inject `Router` service.

```js
constructor(
  private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  private paymentInfoService: PaymentInfoService,
  private router: Router
) {}
```

3. Navigate to the confirmation page through the `onSubmit` function.

```js
onSubmit(): void {
  this.setData(this.checkoutForm.value.cardNumber!);

  this.router.navigate(['/confirmation']);
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bgj6ju?file=src/app/payment-info/payment-info.component.ts)